# find method having trouble excuting a variable in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to display user's email in the view with `User.find(@id).email`,but it gives me an error `couldn't find user without id`,but i am sure the @id carries id 3,because `<%=@id%>` displays 3.Another thing If i hard code the id as `User.find(3).email` it displays the email succesfully.The problem occurs only when i put @id variable as a parameter in the find method,what is going on here?Thank you in advance.

View/**profile.html.erb**

```
   <% @books.each do |book|%>
 <%=book.user_id %>      =>displays 3
 <%= User.find(book.user_id).email %>    =>cant find the id
 <%=User.find(3).email%>       =>works fine
```

Error

```
   Couldn't find User without an ID

    activerecord (3.1.0.rc8) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:302:in   `find_with_ids'
    activerecord (3.1.0.rc8) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:107:in `find'
    activerecord (3.1.0.rc8) lib/active_record/base.rb:441:in `find'
    app/views/deal/show.html.erb:83:in `block (2 levels) in     _app_views_deal_show_html_erb__772775201_99014040'
    activerecord (3.1.0.rc8) lib/active_record/relation.rb:15:in `each'
    activerecord (3.1.0.rc8) lib/active_record/relation.rb:15:in `each'
    app/views/deal/show.html.erb:80:in `block in  _app_views_deal_show_html_erb__772775201_99014040'
    activerecord (3.1.0.rc8) lib/active_record/relation.rb:15:in `each'
    activerecord (3.1.0.rc8) lib/active_record/relation.rb:15:in `each'
    app/views/deal/show.html.erb:13:in `_app_views_deal_show_html_erb__772775201_99014040'
    actionpack (3.1.0.rc8) lib/action_view/template.rb:144:in `block in render'
    activesupport (3.1.0.rc8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:55:in `instrument'
   actionpack (3.1.0.rc8) lib/action_view/template.rb:142:in `render'
   actionpack (3.1.0.rc8) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:40:in  `block     (2levels) in render_template'n/finder_methods.rb:302:in   `find_with_ids'
    activerecord (3.1.0.rc8) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:107:in `find'
    activerecord (3.1.0.rc8) lib/active_record/base.rb:441:in `find'
    app/views/deal/show.html.erb:83:in `block (2 levels) in     _app_views_deal_show_html_erb__772775201_99014040'
    activerecord (3.1.0.rc8) lib/active_record/relation.rb:15:in `each'
    activerecord (3.1.0.rc8) lib/active_record/relation.rb:15:in `each'
    app/views/deal/show.html.erb:80:in `block in  _.........................
```

Comment: I don't have an answer to that one but I have to say I never tried this myself :-). My take on it is that maybe you should avoid find-methods in a view and pass the user to the view instead. That means setting it in the controller @my_user=bla and access the @my_user in the view instead of using the construct you currently use. My 2 cents

Comment: Thank you for the tip.Yes i am aware of that,but In my case that is the only way to get the id,So i have to figure this one out.

Comment: Hm... is 3 in fact the id you would expect? Rephrasing the question: What happens when you add more users? What happens if the user has the id 23 (xyz)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that `@id` is an integer. If it is, I don't see why it wouldn't work. I just tried the exact same thing in my own application and it worked fine.

To ensure that `@id` is an integer and not a string, try this:

```
<%= User.find(@id.to_i).email %>
```

If that does not work, please copy/paste your exact error back here so we can look further into the problem.

Comment: Thank you ,but the @id is an integer,so still doesnt work for me.i have updated the question above .

Comment: This is strange. I'm assuming (because of your tags) that you're running Rails 3.1 (which is the same as me). However, your problem works fine for me.

In your controller, look to where @id is assigned. How is it assigned?